# Bash / Linux Tools for correcting xml

Tags: bash, awk, xml

I am generating a set of '`xml`' files from a '`csv`' file. Some of the fields in csv file contain '`&`' and other invalid xml characters that need to be replaced with their appropriate xml counterpart (i.e. '`&amp;`' in case of '`&`')

Are there any tools using which I can directly correct such xml files?

Comment: How about you encode the problematic entities as part of the CSV to XML transform instead?

Comment: How are you turning your CSV into XML? I would suggest that 'fixing' broken XML isn't the solution, it's 'fixing' the conversion process. Can you offer some sample CSV and XML? I could probably offer a script that'll do it.

Comment: @Warren : Didn't get you. I actually had a xls file (that I converted to csv) containg translations for android application. First column having field id and rest are translation in various languages. I need to put individual strings in their corrosponding values-<locale>/strings.xml file. So I used awk to perfor most of my work, but writing xml escapes in awk gsub is too bad

Comment: @Sobrique : the awk script works now, just the CSV columns need to be fixed as I discribed earlier.

Comment: @SagarPadhye: Sobrique and I are saying that you are fixing a problem that you created in your `awk` script, so the *proper* solution is to either fix the `awk` script or replace it with a better converter. Personally, I use Perl whenever an `awk` solution gets beyond a one-liner. If you're doing the CSV-to-XML purely in Perl, *then* [chaos's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/199096/138) makes sense, because you can encode the problematic entities at the proper level of the conversion process.

Comment: Indeed - the point I'm trying to make is that retroactively fixing XML is a bad thing, and _shouldn't_ be done (the spec says invalid XML should be fatal, for example) because of the number of edge cases and potentially element ambiguity. (It may work in a limited set of cases, but that's a good route to brittle code). So really fixing the generation process is the way to go if you possibly can. And I'm prepared to put together a useful example of how this could work.

Comment: Yes. I have a habit of using awk when it comes to CSV files, so. I am having a second thought on writing a python script (I am not so familiar with Perl, it will be difficult for me to maintain the script). If there was no other option, I would anyways have switched to python.

Comment: Give us a sample, I can offer you an example that isn't hard to maintain! :)

Comment: @Sobrique I was using awk for some time to do the work, but after a change request (handling other forms of CSV,XLS,ODS sheets), I decided to switch to python. It was really easy to code, hardly 50 lines of code with flexibility to handle arbitrary sheets (need to supply metadata to script). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [html-xml-utils](http://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/)
- [xml2](http://ofb.net/~egnor/xml2/)
- [xml-twig-tools](http://www.xmltwig.org/)
- [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: What I did was, instead of dumping the actual string in the xml tag directly
1. Converted string using `xmlstatlet enc` that performs all escaping for me. But this also converts all unicode characters in its xml counterparts. This messes up the xml files for non-english languages. Especially Chinese
2. So using `xmlstarlet fo -e utf-8` I postprocess the files to proper encoding.
This works, for now, but its clumsy as pointed by @Sobrique and @Warren
So I will be looking in python. Will post my solution soon.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `perl`:

```
echo "a&a" | perl -MHTML::Entities -e 'while (<>) {print encode_entities($_, "&");}'
```

Gives:

```
a&amp;a
```

As second parameter, you can specify witch special characters you want to encode.

Comment: I don't think this answer works, on a couple of levels. 1. The OP is giving `&` as an example only. He really wants *all* problematic entities converted. Unlike HTML, XML has a small, finite set of such entities, so you could modify the second parameter to `encode_entities()` to fix this. But, 2. The OP is trying to fix XML already generated, which means your solution is likely to change entities that should remain unchanged. While this is the *real* problem, "don't do that then" is a different answer. :)

Comment: Unfortunately the XML spec is quite clear on fixing broken XML. You shouldn't do it at all. It's _supposed_ to be fatal. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28913945/2566198